# Jquery Datable With dropdown & checkbox in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have a scenario where in i need a jquery datatable to display dropdown & Checkboxes with some normal data column in each row. Has anyone does this so far.

Comment: Have you try this so far?

Answer (score 0):

***Answer to this question can be easily found on google.***

Make sure to go through the official datatables documentation because its really a good one and has many things that we need.

However below is an example by taking help of official datatables documentation and making some changes to it with sample data. (There are really better ways to do it. But this should help you as a starting point on how to add custom HTML to your datatable columns)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 var serverData = [
  {
   "_id": "5aa7ab645a886bb5007f7fd9",
   "isActive": true,
   "age": 24,
   "name": "W W W",
   "friends": [
    {
     "id": 0,
     "name": "W friend1"
    },
    {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "W friend2"
    },
    {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "W friend3"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "_id": "5aa7ab64bd53fc1fc9beb894",
   "isActive": false,
   "age": 28,
   "name": "N N N",
   "friends": [
    {
     "id": 0,
     "name": "N friend1"
    },
    {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "N  friend2"
    },
    {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "N friend3"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({

  data: serverData,
  columns: [
   { data: "name" },
   { data: "age" },
   { data: "isActive" },
   { data: "friends" },
  ],
  'columnDefs': [{
   'targets': 2,
   'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
    let checked = ''
    if (data) {
     return '<input type="checkbox" checked / >';
    }
    else {
     return '<input type="checkbox"  / >';
    }
    return data;
   }
  },
  {
   'targets': 3,
   "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
    var selectInitial = "<select>";
        var selectClosing = "</select>";
        var options = '';
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
     options = options+"<option value="+value.id+">"+value.name+"</option>";
    });
    return selectInitial+options+selectClosing;
   }
  }
  ],
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script><link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css'>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>age</th>
                <th>isActive</th>
                <th>friends</th>
                 
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```